# Is the time for passing arguments typically considered in the runtime of the function being called?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, parameter-passing, benchmarking

When I benchmark (with Xcode developer tools for example) the following piece of code

```
int f (vector<int> BigVector)
{
  // Do Stuff
}

int main()
{
   // Do Stuff
   int x = f(MyBigVector);
}
```

Is the time for passing the argument (by copy in this example) `MyBigVector` typically considered as being time the code spend in `f` or in `main` outside of `f`?

**Is the time for passing arguments typically considered in the runtime of the function being called?**

Comment: Well the copying is part of the call, so I would say that it should be counted as part of the call. Why do you ask? What does it matter *where* the copying is counted?

Comment: It matters for making sense of a benchmark result. But I have to confess that right now, I am asking out of curiosity more than anything else. I don't necessarily understand the details of how arguments are being passed (such as the order for example) and I was hoping to eventually get some more understanding of parameter passing via this question.

Comment: Well it's actually quite easy to test... Create an actual big vector, and pass it to a function which does very little but still enough so it can't be optimized out (like changing a random element of the vector), and profile the call. Do this multiple times, each time with a different sized vector, and plot the times. If you get linear progression of the call time then you know that the copying is counted as part of the call.

Comment: Many benchmarking tools reports both the time in the function itself - and cumulative with all functions called inside it. The latter part often includes the actual function names called in the function. Assuming that is the case and that it is only use of the copy-constructor the report should include the information.